# Correct way to enable and disable voice recording via Bluetooth headset on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android

For an application I'm creating, I need to record a speech fragment that will later be analysed by a Speech-To-Text service.
The latter part works fine, but I found an issue where Android does not automatically use the microphone in the Bluetooth headset when one is connected.

I did quite a bit of reading around Android and Bluetooth and wanted to confirm that what I am doing is correct as I never worked with the Bluetooth feature on Android.

As I don't want to hijack the microphone the entire time the app is open, I've got a system in place that calls the following code:

```
try {
    var audioManager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService (Context.AudioService);
    audioManager.BluetoothScoOn = true;
    audioManager.StartBluetoothSco();
} catch (System.Exception ex) {
    // Handle exception gently
}
```

after I detect the recording is done, I call this:

```
try {
    var audioManager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService (Context.AudioService);
    audioManager.StopBluetoothSco();
    audioManager.BluetoothScoOn = false;
} catch (System.Exception ex) {
    // Handle exception gently
}
```

I was wondering if this is enough? Will this allow recording on all Bluetooth headsets with Microphones? Do I need to something else to route the audio correctly? Are there any pitfalls that I need to take into account?
I haven't set any Bluetooth permissions in the Manifest file.

I tried it with a Bose QuietComfort 35 and it works fine on that headset, but I'm not sure if I need to do anything else to support other types of Bluetooth and headsets.

Comment: If you use the bluetooth headset, you have to use a broadcast to check the  connection has been established to the bluetooth device.And you need the RECORD_AUDIO persmission. Here is code, you can refer to it.(please convert it the C#)https://gist.github.com/JaydipMeghapara/e2682727e0b03f4a6edc2ad8ed299ed5